# Android Studio+MS Open Tech plugin

Tags: android, azure, android-studio

I need to use a azure portal in my app, so I installed the MS Open Tech plugin. In windows everything works great, but when I installed this on OpenSuse i have a small popup windows which tell me   "To coppy Microsoft Services Templates the pl.." . I can't get what this tell me more becouse windows isn't resizable. I can paste in text. What I should paste in this window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok sollution is just in gradle of app add

```
repositories { mavenCentral() }
dependencies {

 compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.2-beta'}
```

Then just syncgradle and Clean and Build App. Hope it help someone :)